# Can anyone explain me how the execution process runs in this java code for Fragments in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio

I wrote this code according to the video tutorial [found here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjh54blnMDKAhXGQBoKHQ6EBdwQtwIIHTAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DdQ6uc__qP-g&usg=AFQjCNG2d5LNgfAG0wO34-wR21QMXAS1yg&sig2=Wcdss0MjHR_vfrajHyqacg)
about Android Fragments, but I can't understand how the flow of execution runs through these codes. As in the tutorial I have made two fragments alone with the Main Activity. The whole program works fine, but I can't understand how the execution flow goes. Please be kind enough to explain me. Here are my source codes, I am
really sorry as they are too long, I posted all of my code. This is the Main Activity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements top_layout_fragment.TopSelectionListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    //overiding the method from the interface
    @Override
    public void createMeme(String top, String bottom) {


        bottom_layout_fragment bottomLayoutFragment = (bottom_layout_fragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
        bottomLayoutFragment.setText(top, bottom);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

this is the activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.example.kasun.fragments.top_layout_fragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        tools:layout="@layout/top_layout_fragment" />

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="320dp"
        android:name="com.example.kasun.fragments.bottom_layout_fragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        tools:layout="@layout/bottum_layout_fragment"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is the top_layout_fragment.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.Activity;
import java.util.ServiceConfigurationError;


public class top_layout_fragment extends Fragment {
    private static EditText firstText, secondText;
    TopSelectionListener activityCommand;


    public interface TopSelectionListener {

        public void createMeme(String top, String bottom);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {

        super.onAttach(activity);

        try {
            activityCommand = (TopSelectionListener) activity;
        }
        catch(ClassCastException e){
            throw new ClassCastException (activity.toString());
        }


    }




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.top_layout_fragment, container, false);



        firstText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.firstText);
        secondText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.secondText);
        final Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        buttonClicked(v);


                    }

                }


        );
        return view;  

    }

    public void buttonClicked(View view) {

        activityCommand.createMeme(firstText.getText().toString(), secondText.getText().toString());


    }
}
```

this is top_layout_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/firstText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:width="320dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/secondText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:width="320dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/firstText"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/secondText"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/button_Texg"
        android:id="@+id/button" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

this is the bottom_layout_fragment.java

```
package com.example.kasun.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class bottom_layout_fragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView topText,bottomText;


    // need to overide the onCreateViewMethod
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottum_layout_fragment,container,false);
        topText=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.topText);
        bottomText=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.bottomText);

        return view;


    }


    public void setText(String topText,String bottomText){
        this.topText.setText(topText);
        this.bottomText.setText(bottomText);

    }
}
```

this is the bottom_layout_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/image1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/topText"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/bottomText"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/topText"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/topText"
        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is set up so you have one activity displaying two fragments. You can see both fragments are included in the activities layout file.

The top fragment needs to communicate with the bottom one to update its text and does so through an interface called `TopSelectionListener`. You will notice that your activity implements that interface. The other important part is the top fragment keeps a reference to your activity using the interface. You can see that in the top fragment's `onAttach` method. The activity displaying this fragment must implement the `TopSelectionListener` interface or else you will get a `ClassCastException` and your application will crash.

```
activityCommand = (TopSelectionListener) activity;
```

When the button is clicked in the top fragment it will call `activityCommand.createMeme(...)` which calls the `createMeme` method in your activity.

The `createMeme` method then looks up a reference to your bottom Fragment and calls the `setText` method on it to update the text it shows.

There is another example how this works in the Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya Do you have any other questions in particular?

Comment: can you explain me what does this line means                            activityCommand = (TopSelectionListener) activity;  What is this activity refering to , does it refer to any activity that implement this fragment or Main activity exists here

Comment: Your `MainActivity` implements the `TopSelectionListener` interface. There you are casting the activity to the interface `TopSelectionListener`. This is necessary so you can later call the `createMeme(...)` method on your activity class when the button is clicked `activityCommand.createMeme(...)`.

Comment: Based on the edit to your comment that activity references the host activity of the fragment. In this case it is `MainActivity`.

Comment: Is this correct, the hosting `activity` is casted to the `TopSelectionListener` interface and it is assign to `activityCommand` object, so when `activityCommand.createMeme(...)` is called, it directly calls to the `createMeme(...)` method in hosting activity

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: thanks @George Mulligan

Comment: one more question, in the flow of this code, when this line runs `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` in `MainActivity.java` ,it calls to the `activity_main.xml` and in it the two fragements are defined as `<fragment .../>`. Is it from these two declarations `<fragment1 .../>`and `<fragment2 .../>` does the `top_layout_fragment.java` and `bottom_layout_fragment.java' get executed?

Comment: Correct again. Another option if you want to later add a fragment to your activity or change a fragment you typically have a place holder `FrameLayout` in the layout file and use a`FragmentManager` to put a fragment in it.

Comment: Thanks again  @George Mulligan